# Issue in setting password for existing in JDBC MS Access Workgroup (MDW) Java

Tags: ms-access, jdbc

Here is my Scenario
I have MS Access DB (MDB file), and work group security file. I have credentials which have all the permit (Administrator user).  This DB and MDW file is created on some other computer and i am using it on my computer now.
What I am able to do till now is, I can log in the DB with different user name and password which are existing in the DB. Verified this by using Correct user name and wrong password It give error, but correct credentials it logins.
Now I need to create a interface In Java to basic functionality.
1. Change password of currently logged user.

**Change password of current user**

Following is my code to change the password

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:"+"mdbTEST";
// mdbTEST is created in System DNS which uses SECURED.MDW file and 
// ExtendedAnsiSQL is set to 1
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "administrator", "hello");

String q = "ALTER USER "+uname+" PASSWORD "+newPass+" '"+oldPass+"'";
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(q);
```

It returns successful.
But when I try to log in the  with the username and new password it says wrong passowrd and even the old password stops working.

Moreover, I tried to read all the username and passwords in the WorkGroup file using some third party software, it shows the new password is updated correctly in the MDW file.

I am using JDK 1.7 on Windows XP 32 bit.
What can be the problem? Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put quotes around the password values to accommodate passwords that contain spaces, you should enclose them in double quotes (`"`). If you enclose them in single quotes (`'`) then the single quote characters become part of the password. For example, after executing my test code...

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ulsTest {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" + 
                    "DBQ=C:\\Users\\Public\\uls\\ulsTest.mdb;" +
                    "SystemDB=C:\\Users\\Public\\uls\\Security.mdw;" +
                    "Uid=Gord;" +
                    "Pwd=obfuscated;" +
                    "ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;");

            String UID = "Tim";
            String oldPWD = "oldpassword";
            String newPWD = "I like Java";

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.execute("ALTER USER " + UID + " PASSWORD \"" + newPWD + "\" \"" + oldPWD + "\""); 
            //  ALTER USER Tim PASSWORD "I like Java" "oldpassword"

            System.out.println("User updated.");

            s.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

...Tim is able to log in using the new password

```
I like Java
```

However, if I change my code to...

```
s.execute("ALTER USER " + UID + " PASSWORD '" + newPWD + "' '" + oldPWD + "'"); 
//  ALTER USER Tim PASSWORD 'I like Java' 'oldpassword'
```

...then the single quotes become part of the new password and Tim must type the password...

```
'I like Java'
```

...(including the single quotes) to log in.

**Side note**: I was hoping that a *parameterized query* might avoid messing with string quoting, but unfortunately the code...

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER USER ? PASSWORD ? ?");
s.setString(1, UID);
s.setString(2, newPWD);
s.setString(3, oldPWD);
s.execute();
```

...fails with the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: can i talk to you on the chat?